# Prevent layouts from overlapping

Tags: android, layout, overlap

I am including 2 layouts on my activity xml, now I want the second layout to not to overlap the first one but I do not really manage to do it....

Attached is my xml. How can I achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_yout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include layout="@layout/content_youtube"
    android:layout_above="@id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Also my 2 included layouts xml's

app_bar_yout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.mlopezitsolutions.blabla.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

content_youtube

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.mlopezitsolutions.blabla.MainActivity">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_above="@id/header"
```

will work only with RelativeLayout. I see that both of your include does not have any layout like FrameLayout, RelativeLayout. Pls place all the 3 XMLs in a RelativeLayout and it has to work. I see it from Android documentation that Include has to be used only for reusability of same components in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Change `match_parent` to your required value eg:`75dp` for `layout_height`s in

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_yout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include layout="@layout/content_youtube"
    android:layout_above="@id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

your main xml code.

Comment: already tried doing it... But the content_youtube layout still overlaps over the header layout.... `
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_yout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_youtube"
        android:layout_above="@id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to place both the "include" in one RelativeLayout and give relative margin between them using either

```
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
```